# Unix Pipes for Command Argument

Tags: unix, io, pipe

I am looking for insight as to how pipes can be used to pass standard output as the arguments for other commands.

For example, consider this case:

```
ls | grep Hello
```

The structure of grep follows the pattern: `grep SearchTerm PathOfFileToBeSearched`.  In the case I have illustrated, the word Hello is taken as the `SearchTerm` and the result of ls is used as the file to be searched.  But what if I want to switch it around?  What if I want the standard output of ls to be the SearchTerm, with the argument following grep being `PathOfFileToBeSearched`?  In a general sense, I want to have control over which argument the pipe fills with the standard output of the previous command.  Is this possible, or does it depend on how the script for the command (e.g., `grep`) was written?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically two options for this: shell command substitution and `xargs`. Brian Agnew has just written about the former. `xargs` is a utility which takes its stdin and turns it into arguments of a command to execute. So you could run

```
ls | xargs -n1 -J % grep -- % PathOfFileToBeSearched
```

and it would, for each file output by `ls`, run `grep -e filename PathOfFileToBeSearched` to grep for the filename output by `ls` within the other file you specify. This is an unusual `xargs` invocation; usually it's used to add one or more arguments at the end of a command, while here it should add exactly one argument in a specific place, so I've used `-n` and `-J` arguments to arrange that. The more common usage would be something like

```
ls | xargs grep -- term
```

to search all of the files output by `ls` for `term`. Although of course if you just want files in the current directory, you can this more simply without a pipeline:

```
grep -- term *
```

and likewise in your reversed arrangement,

```
for filename in *; do
  grep -- "$@" PathOfFileToBeSearched
done
```

There's one important `xargs` caveat: whitespace characters in the filenames generated by `ls` won't be handled too well. To do that, provided you have GNU utilities, you can use `find` instead.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -J % grep -- % PathOfFileToBeSearched
```

to use NUL characters to separate filenames instead of whitespace

Answer (score 9):

`grep` itself will be built such that if you've not specified a file name, it will open stdin (and thus get the output of `ls`). There's no real generic mechanism here - merely convention.

If you want the output of `ls` to be the search term, you can do this via the shell. Make use of a subshell and [substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) thus:

```
$ grep $(ls) filename.txt
```

In this scenario `ls` is run in a subshell, and its stdout is captured and inserted in the command line as an argument for `grep`. Note that if the `ls` output contains spaces, this will cause confusion for `grep`.